# Retrieve xml values using SQL from xml column

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, extract-value

I am trying to retrieve xml value from a column with data stored in xml format using below query in Oracle SQL Developer. But getting this error:

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -
> 00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
> *Cause:
>
> Data type of column is CLOB

```
 SELECT id, 
   extractValue(e.event_data, '/DocumentRequest/RequestUserName')
   "Number of Docks"
   FROM table e
```

eg:

```
<DocumentRequest>
    <RequestUserName>XXXX</RequestUserName>
    <RequestDateTime>XXXX</RequestDateTime>
    <DocSequence>1</DocSequence>
```

Comment: are you sure `e.event_data` is of type `XMLTYPE`?

Answer (score 1):

If the XML is stored as CLOB, then take XMLTYPE:

```
SELECT id,
       EXTRACTVALUE( XMLTYPE(e.event_data), '/DocumentRequest/RequestUserName') AS "Number of Docks"
  FROM table e;
```

Query which uses XMLTABLE:

```
SELECT id,
       col1 AS "Number of Docks"
  FROM table e, XMLTABLE( '/DocumentRequest'
                  PASSING XMLTYPE(e.event_data)
                  COLUMNS col1 PATH 'RequestUserName' );
```

Comment: Note: The EXTRACTVALUE function is deprecated.Use the XMLTABLE function.